# How do I configure Rails to output decimals to the correct precision in form fields?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, decimal, precision

I want to store currencies in my (sqlite and mysql) databases. I'm trying to use the `decimal` column type, with `:scale => 2`.

This isn't behaving as expected. If I save a record with `:rate => 10.50`, it is stored in my sqlite db as `10.5`. In addition, when I output the value in a form field, it is displayed as `10.5`.

I don't want to do hacky string formatting every time I want to display values nicely in Rails forms.

Is there a way to get around this? Is it an sqlite thing? Do I just misunderstand the `decimal` column type?

**Edit:**

To clarify, I want to be able so use the usual form generation methods:

```
- form_for @project do |f|
  = f.text_field :rate
```

If I have to explicitly format the output, I'll have to create extra methods for every decimal attribute:

```
def formatted_rate
  "%.2f" % rate
end

= f.text_field :formatted_rate
```

Are there any other common tricks to force the output formatting, and still use the default Rails formbuilder?

Comment: There's nothing "hacky" about coding your views to display your numbers to two decimal places; that is the ideal solution. When you specify decimal precision, you're specifying a maximum, not a minimum - numbers will never be stored with trailing or leading zeros.

Comment: While not an *exact* duplicate, these answers are almost all applicable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591939/how-can-i-format-the-value-shown-in-a-rails-edit-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a plugin to do this: [currency_text_field](http://github.com/nfm/currency_text_field).

You can define your formats (arguments to `number_with_precision`) in `config/initializers/currency_text_field_initializer.rb`.

Then you use `f.currency_text_field :rate` in your form, with an optional `:format` argument to use a named format in the initializer. Otherwise it uses the `format[:default]` from the initializer.

Same approach as setting the `value` explicitly, but does it all behind the scenes and has named sets of options to `number_with_precision`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Rails ActionView Number Helper [`number_with_precision`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision):

```
number_with_precision(my_number, :precision => 2)
```

Comment: This won't help me to nicely output the value in a form field

Comment: There is also a "number_to_currency" method

Comment: @nfm `<%= f.text_field :rate, :value => number_with_precision(f.object.rate) %>`