# number format in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I format the value shown in a Rails edit field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591939/how-can-i-format-the-value-shown-in-a-rails-edit-field)

all i'm pretty new with ruby on rails. I have a little problem. The format of a number. That number is a decimal one.

here is the view

```
<% has_error = f.object.errors.has_key? :amount %>
  <div class="control-group<%= ' error' if has_error %>">
    <%= f.label :amount, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :amount, :class => 'text_field' %>
      <%= content_tag(:span, f.object.errors[:amount].join(','), :class=> 'help-block') if has_error%>
    </div>
  </div>
```

That renders:

```
<input id="account_entry_amount" class="text_field" type="text" value="0.0" size="30" name="account_entry[amount]" maxlength="20" style="text-align: right;">
```

The value es "0.0" and i want it to be just "0"

Is there any way i can do that in a generic way? I don`t know, express that in a locale file, or initalizer?

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= f.text_field :amount, :class => 'text_field', :value => f.object.amount.to_i %>
```

Comment: this will cut off all decimals, also when present... so if the amount is 4.5, it will display 4

Comment: didn't the OP say he wanted to drop decimals?

Comment: He gave the example of a float without fractional part. So it's not clear what the requirement is. In my opinion he should use the `number_with_precision` helper function

Comment: :) +1, also he accepted the response so if it's not what he expected, it's his problem!! :)