# Rails - Render array attribute as string on failed validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, validation

I have a form field where a user inputs a string of tags `"foo, bar, foobar"`.  This is sent to the controller as `item_params[:tag_list]`.  In the controller my `create` action includes `@item = Item.create(tag_list: item_params[:tag_list])`.  This causes the tag_list attribute to be populated as an array of strings `["foo", "bar", "foobar"]`.

When validation fails I need the input field of the form to be populated with `"foo, bar, foobar"` and not the array of strings.  Is there a way to manipulate this before it goes back to populate the field of the form that failed validation?

Comment: what is the validation?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `acts-as-taggable-on` gem?
Hope this line can resolve you problem

```
f.text_field :tag_list, value: f.object.tag_list.join(', ')
```

Or you have to override `tag_list` method in `Item` model

```
alias_method :array_tag_list, :tag_list
def tag_list
  array_tag_list.join(', ')
end
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get your suggestion to work.  It might be because I am using bootstrap tag inputs and it is causing a problem.  I was able to solve my problem by changing the tag_list attribute to a string if the validation fails.  I did this in the controller `@item.tag_list.remove(item_params[:tag_list], parse: true)` then
`@item.tag_list.add(item_params[:tag_list])`

Comment: I think you have to override `tag_list` method in `Item` model.

    `alias_method :array_tag_list, :tag_list
    def tag_list
      array_tag_list.join(', ')
    end`

Answer (score 0):

Highly surprised that the param is being treated as an array.

---

*Sorry, misread your question (presumed you wanted validation message). Will leave for posterity:*

Whenever you use a `validation`, you get access to [three interpolations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6073499/1143732): `value`, `attribute` & `model`:

```
#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :tag_list, x: { message: "%{value} is not valid" }
end
```

According to the [docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message), you can pass a `Proc` for direct manipulation:

```
#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :tag_list, x: { message: ->(key, data) do
       "#{data[:value].join} is not valid"
    end 
   }
end
```

--

In order to populate the field, you'll want to use the `value` attribute of the attribute, populating with [data from the form object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14225423/1143732):

```
= text_field :tag_list, value: f.object.tag_list.join
```